# PostgreSQL ALTER SEQUENCE in function

Tags: postgresql, sequence

I have trigger function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_aaa() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
DECLARE maxid INTEGER;
BEGIN
    SELECT MAX(id) INTO maxid FROM aaa;
    ALTER SEQUENCE aaa_id_seq RESTART WITH maxid;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

And have error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "$1"
Line 1: ALTER SEQUENCE aaa_id_seq RESTART WITH  $1
```

Why $1 ?
What error?

Answer (score 5):

Maybe use the [`setval` function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-sequence.html#FUNCTIONS-SEQUENCE-TABLE) rather than `alter sequence ... restart with`?

```
SELECT pg_catalog.setval('aaa_id_seq'::regclass, maxid, false);
```

Comment: You usually need that to be `PERFORM`, and that last false needs to go, otherwise you have an off-by-one error.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use [EXECUTE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) for data definition commands (like ALTER) in PL/pgSQL. And you need to `LOCK TABLE aaa IN SHARE MODE;` before calculating MAX(id) to prevent concurrent changes to table data.

Comment: Hmm... if I wrote:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_aaa() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
DECLARE maxid INTEGER;
BEGIN
    SELECT MAX(id) INTO maxid FROM aaa;
    ALTER SEQUENCE aaa_id_seq RESTART WITH 999;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

All good...

Comment: Because you did not use any variable in your statement and PL/pgSQL parser was not confused. Maybe I should write "_dynamic_ data definition commands".

Answer (score 0):

Your table is probably empty so

```
SELECT MAX(id) INTO maxid FROM aaa;
```

returns `NULL`;

Change the query to

```
SELECT COALESCE(MAX(id), <some_appropriate_value>) INTO maxid FROM aaa;
```